# Create periodic function from combining non-periodic functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm studying recurrent neural networks which often use tanh as an activator function which is not periodic. However in research and papers it's shown that these recurrent neural nets can exhibit oscillatory, periodic behavior.

If one where to use a linear supperposition of tanh's with weights such as ->

```
A(n+1) = Tanh( Sum(Tanh for B (n,index)WeightConstant(index), index) )
B(n+1) = Tanh( Sum(Tanh for A (n,index)WeightConstant(index), index) )
```

I suppose the gut's of the question, is how can one find the conditions for which arbitrary combination of non-periodic functions can create periodic ones? I've doing something with Fourier Expansion and Transformations, but I'm lost.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!